# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined

Tags: angular, authentication, post, angular-httpclient

I need to request my API (https://myurl.com/login) for login (username + password) in angular 7.3. When i use POST without user.models.ts I received a bad request error. When I use this model I have this error:

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined."

user.model.ts

```
export class User {
constructor(public username: string,
            public password: string) {
    }
}
```

login.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {LoginService} from '../services/login.service';
import {User} from '../models/user.model';


@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private loginService: 
LoginService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        this.user.username = form.value['login'];
        this.user.password = form.value['password'];
        this.loginService.LoginUser(this.user).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}
```

login.service.ts:

```
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    LoginUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.post<User>('https://captn-boat-api.herokuapp.com/login', user)
        ;
    }
}
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="login--already-registered">
      <span class="login--screen-title">J'ai déjà un compte</span>

      <form class="login" method="GET" action="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">

        <div class="input--field text dark">
          <label for="login" class="control-label"><svg class="icon icon-envelope"><use xlink:href="#icon-envelope"></use></svg> E-mail</label>
          <input id="login" name="login" type="text" placeholder="" value="" ngModel>

        </div>

        <div class="input--field password dark">
          <label for="password" class="control-label"><svg class="icon icon-lock"><use xlink:href="#icon-lock"></use></svg> Mot de passe</label>
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="" value="" ngModel>

        </div>

        <div class="input--field checkbox dark">
          <label for="session"><input id="session" name="" value="session" type="checkbox"> se souvenir de moi</label>
        </div>

        <div class="login--submit">

          <button class="button button btn-submit" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never instantiate user..... You can change your onSubmit as follows

instead of:

```
this.user.username = form.value['login'];
this.user.password = form.value['password'];
```

do this....

```
this.user = new User(form.value['login'], form.value['password']);
```

but do you really need the User class? why not just define an IUser interface instead of a User class and do...

```
this.user = form.value;
this.loginService.LoginUser(this.user).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Best way, with formGroup....

in the html.... make the following changes (this includes required validation for username and password, and disabled submit button if form is invalid)....

```
<form class="login" method="GET" action="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" [formGroup]="formGroup">

<input id="login" name="login" type="text" formControlName="username">
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" formControlName="password">

<button class="button button btn-submit" type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">
```

Then, in the component ts file....

```
formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
```

and in your OnSubmit function....

```
this.user = this.formGroup.value;
this.loginService.LoginUser(this.user).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But now i have the same issue that the begining "ERROR 400 Bad request" I don't know where is the problem, if Im sending wrong request or if i made something wrong when i coded it.

Request URL: https://my-url.com/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 52.209.88.81:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: @CorentinBetz Maybe you have more fields in your form? what is the request it is sending, and what is the back end expecting? Also, I would recommend instead of ngForm creating a formGroup and using the formGroup's value for this.user, so you know exactly what is defined.

Comment: I've checked the console.log(user.username) and it display :

undefined (instead of username)
Password (it's works for the password)

Comment: @CorentinBetz If you want to edit your question to include the html, I will edit  my answer to include a FormGroup

Comment: @CorentinBetz Edited to add support for Angular forms (also included example validation for no reason at all).... This is a much better pattern.

Comment: it Display me this error "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'."

Comment: @CorentinBetz Make sure you import ReactiveFormsModule in your module

Comment: it's imported but said me it's not used. I see an error in login.component.html on [formGroup] "Property formGroups not provided by any application directive nor by form element"

Comment: @CorentinBetz in your ngModule (the same ngModule where you declared this component), you included ReactiveFormsModule in the imports array?

Comment: @CorentinBetz No, not in the component. in your NgModule, in the imports array.

Comment: Yes my bad i have the username and the password in the console, but still the same bad request.

Comment: Check network tab on the debugging tools in chrome to make sure the request you're sending is correct.... It sounds like what your api is expecting is something different.... If you're sending the correct request, then it's an error with the api.

Comment: The console display this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url-api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and this is the network information tab:

Request URL: https://url-api.com/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 54.194.235.52:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Your api needs to enable CORS. How you do that depends on what language and framework you are using for your API. You should search stackOverflow for how to do it, chances are it's been asked before.

Comment: Ok i will search, Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inilialize `user`.

Replace `user: User;` by `user: User= new User` or `user: User = {};`

Comment: user: User = {}; Will give a type Error